# Induced current in circuit with falling side

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

There is a physics problem from the 2016 version of national test about induction that I'm not certain about.  In it, there are two long standing vertical metal rods connected by a horizontal resistor.  A horizontal rod is allowed slide down the two vertical rods, and the whole setup is bathed in a magnetic field B, perpendicular to the plane of the loop. As the rod falls, the area of circuit and thus the flux increases.  The problem involves solving for the induced current, and also the equation of motion with the rod reaching a terminal velocity.

The official published solution for equation of motion treats the magnetic field as a constant, and the equation reduces to a second order differential equation. I recognize that the induced current produces its own field that is antiparallel to the bathing field.  The solution I've seen doesn't seem to account for this subtraction of fields.

Is treating the field as constant just a simplifying assumption, or is there physics here I'm not seeing? My intuition is that the field is not constant.  I'm curious about the structure of the equation that describes the motion.  Is this a known phenomena that has a solved analytic solution?

Thanks,

Comment: Due to the induced EMF there will be current in the circuit. This current will cause the horizontal wire to experience a force upwards. Try forming your equations considering a constant original field  which exerts a force on the resistor wire as it move downwards.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I see that the the induced current leads to a force on the wire = ILB.  What I'm asking about is since the induced current produces a magnetic field that partially counteracts the original field, the change in flux is d (BA)/dt, but where B is no longer a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is often necessary to consider the effect of induced field of a piece of wire on EMF in the circuit. For example, if the wire is shaped in a form of coil (solenoid or torus), and the external voltage/current in the wire is changing rapidly, the induced field has strong influence on total EMF and has to be considered (usually by assigning inductive impedance to the coil).

There are common cases where the effect of the induced field is negligible, like for a piece of straight wire where changes of external voltage are not too rapid (for high-frequency oscillating external voltage, even straight piece of wire may experience strong self-induction effect).

In your case, it seems that the changes of current will be slow (big rod falling in Earth's gravity) and the piece of wire has very low self-inductance (straight rod), so it seems the simplification you describe is warranted. The EMF can be calculated with good accuracy from the fiction that total magnetic flux is that due to external field only.